# Looping AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, android-asynctask

I have custom `AsyncTask` (ListDownloadTask) that download data and updates UI. I want to make it forever while activity opened. So after AsyncTask did the work it must be scheduled. There are delays between attempts.

I tried to use timer but the problem is `new ListDownloadTask().execute();` must be invoked from UI thread.

Now i have timer that generates message for `Handler`. That seems ugly to me. What is best practice?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// ...
    new ListDownloadTask().execute();
}

private static final long DOWNLOAD_UPDATES_DELAY = 5 * 1000;
private final Timer mUpdatesDownloaderTimer = new Timer(true);

Handler mDownloadTrigger = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
        new ListDownloadTask().execute();
        return true;
    }
});

private void scheduleUpdatesDownload() {
    mUpdatesDownloaderTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDownloadTrigger.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }, DOWNLOAD_UPDATES_DELAY);
}

private class ListDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Long, String, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //...
        scheduleUpdatesDownload();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. I should use service from very beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) that is kinda similar to what you want to do. It might be better to use a Local Service also though.

Answer (score 0):

Try Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed or Handler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service and bind to it in your activity.